# Change phone number format

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I have phone number field in database. It has already data.

I want to change my phone number format to "XXX-XXX-XXXX"
Current database has no any phone format.

So there may be garbage data. I have already applied validation for new records but now I want to change my existing data also.

Is there any specific way through that I can change my existing data. And make all phone numbers to follow this format.

Please advice.

Comment: Strip off all non-numeric characters from the database, and apply any desired formatting 1. in the client app;  2. in SQL which selects the data from the database;, or 3. create a computed column on the table which applies the formatting for you on the fly and `Select` that column instead of the unformatted column value

Comment: Well, I want to do that. But how? Any query will help a lot.

Comment: You will first need to remove any existing formatting characters. Most probable characters are ()- and a space. My preference would be to leave the formatting to the front end application and get all the formatting characters and logic out of the database.

Answer (score 2):

Create function to remove the non-numeric data and do the formatting

```
CREATE FUNCTION [UDF_STRIP_NONNUMERIC_DATA](@str VARCHAR(8000))
RETURNS VARCHAR(8000)
AS
  BEGIN
      WHILE Patindex('%[^0-9]%', @str) > 0
        BEGIN
            SET @str = Stuff(@str, Patindex('%[^0-9]%', @str), 1, '')
        END

      RETURN @str
  END
```

You can use `STUFF` function to inset the `-` between `phone` number

```sql
Select left(Stuff(Stuff(dbo.[UDF_STRIP_NONNUMERIC_DATA](Phone),4,0,'-'),8,0,'-'),12)
From yourtable
```

If you are using `SQL SERVER 2012+` use can use [**`FORMAT`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/hh213505.aspx) function (thanks to  LukStorms, who mentioned it in comment)

```
SELECT Format(Cast(dbo.[Udf_strip_nonnumeric_data](Phone) AS BIGINT), '###-###-####')
FROM   yourtable
```

To update

```sql
Update yourtable 
   SET phone = left(Stuff(Stuff(dbo.[UDF_STRIP_NONNUMERIC_DATA](Phone),4,0,'-'),8,0,'-'),12)
```

**Demo**

```sql
declare @str  varchar(100)= '9225-123-4567'

select left(Stuff(Stuff(dbo.[UDF_STRIP_NONNUMERIC_DATA](@str),4,0,'-'),8,0,'-'),12)
```

**Result :** `922-512-3456`

Comment: Not working as expected Old Data: 9225-123-4567 - Using your query converted to: 92-5-1-3-4567

Comment: Now its not working with records which has correct data. Try with "555-555-5555". It will be converted to "555-555-55"

Comment: Well, result should not be "922-512-34567". I want to convert it to "922-512-3456"

Comment: Also check for "(832) 823-3183", its converted to "(83-2) -8233183". I want to convert all phone numbers to "XXX-XXX-XXXX" format.

Comment: @PiyushKhatri - Well you need to add all theses info in question in first place. What are the other possible characters other than `-`, `(` and `)` ?

Comment: @PiyushKhatri  Btw, if your SQL server isn't to old then it should have the FORMAT function.  As in `select format(cast(replace(@str,'-','') as bigint),'###-###-#####')`

Comment: @LukStorms Thanks buddy totally forgot about it. Added it in answer

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @phone varchar(24)
set @phone = '(334)789-4532'
--set @phone = '314789-4532'
--set @phone = '3457894532'
--set @phone = '534-789-4532'

SELECT
    LEFT(N,3) + '-' + SUBSTRING(N,4,3) + '-' + RIGHT(N,4)
FROM
    (SELECT CAST(CAST((
            SELECT SUBSTRING(@phone, Number, 1)
            FROM master..spt_values
            WHERE Type='p' AND Number <= LEN(@phone) AND
                SUBSTRING(@phone, Number, 1) LIKE '[0-9]' FOR XML Path(''))
        AS xml) AS varchar(MAX)) as N) as N
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, to replace all non-numeric characters, look at [this](https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/6518/help-using-replace-with-wildcard-matching-pattern.html).

Here is a sample script (copied from that link) to show you how it works (You'll need to modify this to fit your table name and column names:

```
-- Step 1: creates table to use to hold every char in every phone number
if object_id('dbo.tally') is not null drop table dbo.tally   
   select top 10000 --change to fit max length of phone number
     identity(int,1,1) as n
   into dbo.tally
   from master.dbo.syscolumns sc1,
        master.dbo.syscolumns sc2

-- add pk to maximize performance
  alter table dbo.tally
     add constraint pk_tally_n 
        primary key clustered (n) with fillfactor = 100

-- Step 2: Create temporary table holding three bad phone numbers  
 declare @phonetable table 
   (uniqueid int identity(1,1), 
   phone_number varchar(500)) 
   insert into @phonetable (phone_number) 
   select '01234-567-890' union 
   select '012345 6789ext' union 
   select 'n/a' union select '...12345.....';

 -- Step 3: identify, for every character, whether it is a number or not,
           and remove the non-numeric ones
 with cte (uniqueid, phone_number, goodchar, badchar) as
 ( select uniqueid, phone_number, 
        case when substring(phone_number,N,1) not like '%[^0-9]%' 
             then substring(phone_number,N,1) end as goodchar, 
        case when substring(phone_number,N,1) like '%[^0-9]%' 
             then substring(phone_number,N,1) end as badchar
   from @phonetable , Tally  
   where phone_number like '%[^0-9]%' and N <= len(phone_number) )
   select distinct phone_number, 
        isnull( stuff ( 
                  ( SELECT '' + goodchar 
                FROM cte t1 
        where t1.UniqueID = t2.UniqueID 
          FOR XML PATH ( '' ) ) , 1 , 0 , '' ) ,'')  
                        as clean_phone_number from cte t2
```

to display the numbers with formatting, just extract the appropriate pieces and re-concatenate them with the dashes.

```
Select case len(phone) 
       When 10  then left(phone, 3) + '-' + 
                     substring(phone, 4,3) + '-' + 
                     substring(phone, 7,4)`
       When 7 then left(phone, 3) + '-' + 
                   substring(phone, 4,4)
       Else '' end
```

To create a computed column

```
Alter table Add Column FormattedPhone as 
  case len(phone) 
       When 10  then left(phone, 3) + '-' + 
                     substring(phone, 4,3) + '-' + 
                     substring(phone, 7,4)`
       When 7 then left(phone, 3) + '-' + 
                   substring(phone, 4,4)
       Else '' end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind a UDF

```
Select [dbo].[udf-Str-Format-Phone]('334)789-4532')
```

Returns

```
334-789-4532
```

The UDF

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Format-Phone] (@S varchar(max))
Returns varchar(25)
AS
Begin
    Declare @Return varchar(25)

    ;with cte0(N) As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N))
        , cteN(N) As (Select Top (Len(@S)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From cte0 N1, cte0 N2)
        , cteS(S) As (Select Substring(@S,N,1) From cteN Where Substring(@S, N, 1) LIKE '[0-9]' FOR XML Path(''))

    Select @Return = IIf(Len(S)>=10,Stuff(stuff(S,4,0,'-'),8,0,'-'),Stuff(S,4,0,'-')) From cteS
    Return @Return

End
-- Syntax : Select [dbo].[udf-Str-Format-Phone]('(334)789-4532')  -- Returns 334-789-4532
-- Syntax : Select [dbo].[udf-Str-Format-Phone]('Phone:7894532')  -- Returns 789-4532
```